# Request.Url.AbsoluteUri and Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri are empty sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I use `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to detect requested urls, but there are some requests without **Url** and **Url Referrer**

here is the code :

```
db.Visits.Add(new Visit {
    Url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri,
    UrlReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
});
```

Results :

[image: The result of saving urls]

- Is it normal?
- Should I block these requests?
- Are they search engine's crawlers?
- How should I behave?

Comment: you want current URL and last refer URL?

Comment: @jishansiddique - Exactly

Comment: @Hooman, did you found an answer? I'm facing the same problem (there's one server from where I can only read the host and schema, I don't have path value nor query string).

Answer (score 2):

First, you check Your **Request** object.

You may at times need to get different values from URL.

Below example shows different ways of extracting different parts of URL

EXAMPLE: (Sample URL)

"http://localhost:6061/MyWebSite/Default2.aspx?QueryStringValue=1"

CODE

```
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
Response.Write("<br/> " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
```

OUTPUT below Please check

```
localhost
localhost:6061
6061
/MyWebSite/Default2.aspx
/MyWebSite
http://localhost:6061/MyWebSite/Default2.aspx?QueryStringValue=1
/MyWebSite/Default2.aspx?QueryStringValue=1
```

Note: Normally above code working in ASP.NET WEB FROM if you want In MVC you need to change some routing based values.